# Raspberry as FXO

Tags: gpio, audio, sip

So I was thinking to build my own voip system for my home. I've got a landline coming to my house. I was researching FXO cards and found out that they are really expensive so i'm thinking if i can take a old phone connect it to the landline and wire each button to the raspberry and the mic and speaker to a sound card after that i want to create a script so I can add it to an asterisk server so i can make calls. So my questions are:

- Is it possible

Comment: Welcome -- but you have a number of distinct questions here, not all of which are appropriate.  Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works, and read ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).  You need to focus on one specific, concrete, objective question at a time.

Comment: It sounds like you might want to start by researching how FXO's work on a low level (what kind of signals they use, etc.), which would be more appropriate to our larger sibling site, [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).  Keep in mind that you are expected to make an effort at research yourself first, and your questions should reflect this, i.e., do not ask people to regurgitate widely available public information, instead, e.g., ask about specific pieces of information that you do not understand.

Comment: `old phone connect it to the landline and wire each button` .... an old dialup modem can be used for dialing the phone number ..... some of the modems have a voice interface ............ you can also buy a cordless phone that has bluetooth connectivity and allows smartphones to make landline calls